# sql statement..how to merge this code?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

```
dgvall("SELECT department FROM tblvoter GROUP BY department", dgvdepartment)
dgvall("SELECT COUNT(tblvoter.department) AS 'votes', department FROM tblvoter WHERE voterstatus = '1'", dgv123)
```

How can I make this into one SQL statement, or merge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    department,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '1' THEN 1 END) AS voted,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '0' THEN 1 END) AS no_vote
FROM tblvoter
GROUP BY department;
```

This would ensure that every department appears in your result set, even if that department has no voters.  The potential problem with your current is that if a department has no voters, then it will be filtered off entirely from the result set.

Comment: Okay. how about i add another voterstatus = '0' as did not vote. how do i add that?

Comment: dgvall("SELECT course as 'COURSE', COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '1' THEN 1 END) AS 'VOTED', COUNT(CASE WHEN voterstatus = '0' THEN 1 END) AS 'NOT YET VOTED' FROM tblvoter where course = 'BSIT' or course = 'BSCE'", dgvcourse)

Comment: can you correct that also? i'm trying another code for another datagriview

Comment: @FLASHHHHH You should open a new question.  I don't know what you want here.